# Create a validated list from a comma delimited single cell derived from a 2D Index-Match operation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

*** Read for extra information ***
I have a 3D data set. The third dimension of this data set is dependent on an outside integer value. For ease of use and to keep the task achievable with my knowledge I created a 2D table that contains comma delimited cells representing the third dimension. The main issue is the outside integer that actively mutates the 2D table.

*** Main Question ***
I need to create a validated list, drop-down cell from a comma delimited list located in a single cell on a separate sheet within the same workbook. The comma delimited list is generated from a 2D INDEX-MATCH function. I am trying to complete this via a VBA function to easily select inputs and call a subroutine to create the validated list. (If the subroutine is not necessary; disregard)

2D Table
[image: 2D Table]

Output Cells
[image: Output Cells]
*Ignore DCTG for now, that will be the same process but for a different 3D data set.

I would like a function to receive (InputCell, OutputCell). InputCell is dependent on three other prior selected data points (outside integer referenced in background, and the x and y of the table) and its current code is

```
=INDEX(Rmag_For_Casting_Material,MATCH(Updated!E7,RMAG_Casting_Method,0),MATCH(Updated!E6,RMAG_Material_Class,0))
```

Which when given to the validate data list tool creates a single option list of "A,B,C,D" and not a mutli option list of "A","B","C",...

*** Current Research ***

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   AddCSVListValidation "Task", "A1", "A2"
End Sub

Sub AddCSVListValidation(sheet, cellSource, cellTarget)
    txt = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cellSource).Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cellTarget) = "Select your values here"
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Range(cellTarget).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="a,b,c"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

I believe this creates a subroutine that would create a validated list, but would need multiple copies for each time I create a new validated list in different cell. Or could I replace the "Task", "A1", "A2" and rerun the subroutine? I am having trouble even running the subroutine on its own. Is this "Task" sheet name necessary?

I believe this code is a great backbone for what I want to do, but I am not proficient enough to create a function and parse information between the sub and function.

Comment: Gosh, you've written such a detailed question and nobody answered you. Let me start by saying that `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="a,b,c"` should probably be `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=txt` otherwise your method will never be dynamic. Then, it might help if you really narrow the focus of your question.

Comment: You said, _could I replace the "Task", "A1", "A2" and re run the subroutine?_  The short answer is, yes, of course you could. You can run it as many times as you like and get all kinds of cool validation lists. So, I feel like must be asking something else. What is preventing you from doing it?

Comment: @stonegiant thank you for response. I was able to implement what you suggested by changing "a,b,c" into "txt". Also the reason I now realize I wanted to incorporate a function with the sub routine was to have it change based on other selections. I was however able to achieve this with a second subroutine that checks for relevant cell updates and reruns the validated list subroutine. I still feel that if I were able to incorporate some use of function that it would be "cleaner," but this solution does work effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions

Instead of applying the data validation to all the cells through VBA you can do this

1. Crete a VBA code to separate the comma separated text to insert each
   value in separate cell and make a range having a list of these
   values
2. Create a named list referring to this range
3. Apply data validation rule to all the required cells using this
   named list

Find below the VBA code to do that

```
Sub makeNamedRange()

    sheet_name = "Sheet1"

    input_text = Sheets(sheet_name).Range("B1").Value
    arr_text = Split(input_text, ",")

    i = 1
    For Each elm In arr_text
        Sheets(sheet_name).Range("C" & i).Value = elm
        i = i + 1
    Next

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="data_validation_list", RefersTo:="=" & sheet_name & "!$C$1:$C$" & i - 1

End Sub
```

Notes

1. The code is taking the comma separated text from B1
2. and extracting its values to C1 to C(n)
3. You can change that in your sheet
4. You can call this function on sheet open or any other event according to your requirements to update the list with new data.